# How to restart the loop for HTML and CSS keyframe animation

Tags: html, css

I have created this animation. I need help to make it loop (i.e run nonstop). My attempt to loop results in the individual items stacking on top of each other which causes the normal behavior of the code to stop which is to display each items one after another, independently. I only want to use css for this. I animated the items properly I just don't want to trigger the code to run again on re-saving the code. I want to automate it through the loop.

What I have tried.

```css
    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      height: 300px; /* Adjust based on desired container height */
    }

    .box {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute; /* Set position to absolute */
      top: 50px; /* Common top value */
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
      animation: mymove .5s;
      padding: 30px;
      opacity: 0; /* Initially set opacity to 0 */
    }

    #div5 {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute; /* Set position to absolute */
      top: 50px; /* Common top value */
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      color: #000;
      font-weight: bold;
      animation: bounceAndDisappear 1.5s ease-in-out 5s 2; /* Bounce and disappear animation */
      opacity: 0; /* Initially set opacity to 0 */
    }

    i {
      font-size: 200px;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .fa-file-circle-check {
      color: green;
    }
    #div2 {animation-timing-function: ease;}

    @keyframes mymove {
      0% { left: 500px; opacity: 0; }
      100% { left: 400px; opacity: 1; }
    }

    #div2 { animation-delay: 1s; }
    #div3 { animation-delay: 2s; }
    #div4 { animation-delay: 3s; }
    #div5 { animation-delay: 4s; }

    @keyframes bounceAndDisappear {
      0%, 100% { left: 400px; transform: translateY(0) ; opacity: 0; }
      50% { left: 400px; transform: translateY(-20px); opacity: 1; }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
     <div id="div1"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i><p>Processing</p></div>
      
    </div>
  
    <div class="box">
      <div id="div2"><i class="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i><p>Processing</p></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="div3"><i class="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i><p>Processing</p></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div id="div4"><i class="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i><p>Processing</p></div>
      
    </div>
  
    <div class="box">
      <div id="div5"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-circle-check"></i><p>Done</p></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

<div></div>
```